# get the fields in the input document after $group in aggregation pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The problem I am facing is that how to access the original document after one group operation and also carry the fields after $group in aggregation pipeline in MongoDB.

For example: [ group, unwind, group]

Original document is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("361de42f1938e89b179dda42"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("9424021bafbde55512e39b83"),
"candidate_id" : ObjectId("54f65356294160421ead3ca1")
"OVERALL_SCORE" : 150,
"SCORES" : [ 
    { "NAME" : "asd", "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 28}, { "NAME" : "acd", "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 36 }, { "NAME" : "abc", "OBTAINED_SCORE" : 40}
 ]
}
```

Aggregation function:

```
 db.coll.aggregate([ $group : { _id : { user_id : "$user_id"}, BEST_SCORE : { $max : "$OVERALL_SCORE"}, AVG_SCORE : { $avg : "$OVERALL_SCORE" }}} ])
```

Below is the sample output (after 1st group):

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("9424021bafbde55512e39b83")
        },
        "BEST_SCORE" : 150,
        "AVG_SCORE" : 132
    }
],
"ok" : 1
 }
```

Question is: (I don't know whether it can be achievable)
I want the **fields in the original documents** (input to aggregation).

For ex: 
1) unwind "SCORES" which is in the original document and next group by "candidate_id", "user_id".

2) I want "BEST_SCORE", "AVG_SCORE" (after 1st group) fields to access in the 2nd group also.

Aggregation function should look something like this:

```
   db.coll.aggregate([ $group : { _id : { user_id : "$user_id"}, BEST_SCORE : { $max : "$OVERALL_SCORE"}, AVG_SCORE : { $avg : "$OVERALL_SCORE" }}}, { $unwind : "$SCORES"}, /*problem is--after group operation "SCORES" field which is in original document not available */ { $group : _id : { NAME: "$SCORES.NAME"}, AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE: { $avg : "$SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE"}} **/*problem is--this is also in the original document*/** ])
```

Output should look like this:

```
   "BEST_SCORE": 150,                     //after 1st group
  "AVG_SCORE": 132,                       //after 1st group
  "SCORES": [                             //problem --- unwind "SCORES" and then group which is actually will not be available after 1st group (get this from original document)
    {
      "NAME": "abc",
      "AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE": 25.5
    },
    {
      "NAME": "asd",
      "AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE": 24
    },
    {
      "NAME": "acd",
      "AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE": 32
    }
  ]
```

Could any one please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. You can only really "keep" what is within the "grouping  key" or otherwise can be retained by one of the grouping operators like you are doing with other values or optionally something like $last or $push. What would be the point of keeping other fields and what would you expect as a final result.

Comment: `$$ROOT` only refers to the "whole document" at the stage of aggregation where it is called. So once you have altered the document in one stage, then the value of  `$$ROOT` is that altered form when accessed in another stage. You cannot see what the document looked like before other changes. As I suggested before, It is not really clear what your intended results are. If you edit your question to show what you expect, then people may be able to advise on an approach to get there.

Comment: I have edited.. hope now it is more clear..

Comment: You are loosing us at where `"name": "asd"` is supposed to come from. Unless it is part of the "SCORES" array documents then you are likely out of luck here. Is it really an element inside those array documents?

Comment: Let's not chat. It's either a yes or no answer. Otherwise please alter the details of your question to explain where data is supposed to come from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When grouping with something that you want to retain the values for all considered documents in a group you need to use [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). Catch is, that this is an array. So you process [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) twice, and also have two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    {  "$group" : { 
        "_id": "$user_id", 
        "BEST_SCORE": { "$max": "$OVERALL_SCORE" },
        "AVG_SCORE": { "$avg": "$OVERALL_SCORE" },
        "SCORES": { "$push": "SCORES" }
    }}, 

    // SCORES in an array of arrays. Unwind twice
    { "$unwind": "$SCORES" },
    { "$unwind": "$SCORES" },

    // Group for averages on elements
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "user_id": "$_id",
            "NAME": "$SCORES.name"
        },
        "BEST_SCORE": { "$first": "$BEST_SCORE" },
        "AVG_SCORE": { "$first": "$AVG_SCORE" }
        "AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE": { "$avg": "$SCORES.OBTAINED_SCORE" } 
    }},

    // Group to user_id
    { "$group": {
        "user_id": "$_id.user_id",
        "BEST_SCORE": { "$first": "$BEST_SCORE" },
        "AVG_SCORE": { "$first": "$AVG_SCORE" }
        "SCORES": { "$push": {
            "NAME": "$_id.NAME",
            "AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE": "$AVG_OBTAINED_SCORE"
        }}     
    }}
])
```

You might be tempted to consider using `$unwind` before the first `$group`, but if you did then the calculated averages would be affected by the number of elements present in the array that was being "un-wound". So the "double $unwind" is a necessary process here.

Comment: If any fields to be carried forward to the next pipeline operator, we need to use $push or $addToSet.

Comment: @user3805045 You need to do something, but those would be appropriate to this use case.

Comment: The main difference between $push and $addToSet is that push adds the elements retaining their order (whatever it was in the previous stages), whereas $addToSet adds the elements in no particular order: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/